# VBA issue with finding cells

Tags: vba, excel, input

So I've been working on a Holiday calendar for employees and I've got a problem which I cannot seem to find a solution for.

I have two buttons which are assigned to a VBA script and I'm having an issue with a holiday entry for it. I can't seem to be able to select a specific cell from the user form inputs to output the data. The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
'Holiday Calendar.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
'ActiveCell = (A5)
'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Employees")) + 1
NextRow = 5
Do Until Sheets("Holiday Calendar").Cells(NextRow, 4) = Username.Value
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
Loop

'Transfer information

Cells(NextRow, 6).Value = TypeOfLeave.Value
Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = (EndDate.Value) + 1 - (StartDate.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub




Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As 
Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Empty UsernameTextBox
Username.Value = ""

'Empty TypeOfLeave ComboBox
TypeOfLeave.Clear

'Fill TypeOfLeaveComboBox
    With TypeOfLeave
    .AddItem "AL - Anual Leave"
    .AddItem "WFH - Work From Home"
    '.AddItem ""
End With

'Set Focus on UsernameTextBox
Username.SetFocus
End Sub
```

This is how the code for the whole user form looks.

Now what I need help with is when the user `inputs` the start and end date of their holiday it will then look for the `username` within the `spreadsheet` and place "**AL-Anual Leave**" and "**WFH - Work From Home**" accordingly in the dates that the user has provided.

So what I need is a piece of code that will find the date within the `spreadsheet` from the user form and `input` the values "**Al**" or "**WFH**"

If any of this is unclear please let me know and ill explain. I tried including pictures but don't have enough reputation so it's much harder. I can send the images in email if needed to explain better.

Comment: unfortunately since im using a company work desk in the office i can not add pictures online due to confidentiality

Comment: It looks like username.value is set to "" when you initialize the form, but I don't see it get saved with a value at any other point.  I would assume it should go in the CommandButton1_Click

Comment: comand button 1 is just submit

Comment: Ok.  To me, I just don't see where Username.Value gets updated.  It looks like it is set to "" in initialize.  It likely needs to be saved from that user form before you run the macro.

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean. Maybe this will help
The username is already on the spreadsheet and all the holiday entry needs to do is find the username which is does but then all i need to do is output the holiday dates into the same row. Where the calendar starts from column K. and every cell accounts for one day so cell K3 is 01/01/2015 and L3 is 02/01/2015 and so on till the end of the 2015 calendar

Comment: im pretty basic with vba this is the first thing i have ever done so any technical stuff could you explain to me first

Answer (score 0):

Based on our comments from above, I would like if you could give this code snippet a try first and let me know if it still isn't working.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
'Holiday Calendar.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
'ActiveCell = (A5)
'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Employees")) + 1

Username.Value = UsernameTextBox.Value
NextRow = 5
Do Until Sheets("Holiday Calendar").Cells(NextRow, 4) = Username.Value
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
Loop

'Transfer information

Cells(NextRow, 6).Value = TypeOfLeave.Value
Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = (EndDate.Value) + 1 - (StartDate.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub




Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As 
Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Empty UsernameTextBox
Username.Value = ""

'Empty TypeOfLeave ComboBox
TypeOfLeave.Clear

'Fill TypeOfLeaveComboBox
    With TypeOfLeave
    .AddItem "AL - Anual Leave"
    .AddItem "WFH - Work From Home"
    '.AddItem ""
End With

'Set Focus on UsernameTextBox
Username.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: code in itself works it just doesnt find the start date and put "AL" or "WFH" into it it just puts it in ROW F whereas the calendar in itself starts from ROW K if it makes it easier could you give me your email and i could send over a screenshot of what i currently have. Im going out of the office atm so i could send it tomorrow

Comment: Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = (EndDate.Value) + 1 - (StartDate.Value)
is ment to calculate the amount the person is going on holiday for so i was wandering if i can use that value to input the same amount of "AL" or "WFH" into the calendar accordingly